# Filter and count rows with two conditions R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, row, special-characters

I am trying to filter out rows that consists of letters (no special characters like dots, brackets, etc.), which have from 2 to  letters. I want to also count their frequencies.

The table

```
df = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                col1 = c(
                "[is]",
                "[is]",
                "[is]+[is]",
                "complex",
                "ta",
                "ta",
                "ta ta pa",
                "pum",
                "wam",
                "wam wam","puk","[is]+ pa", "[is]+ pa", "ta","wa pa [is] pa","wak wak")
                )
```

It looks like:

```
#         col1
#         
# 1       [is]
# 2       [is]
# 3  [is]+[is]
# 4    complex
# 5         ta
# 6         ta
# 7         ta
# 8   ta ta pa
# 9        pum
# 10       wam
# 11   wam wam
```

The output should look like this:

```
col1       N

ta         3
pum        1
wam        1
```

I used `dplyr` to grouped the col1 (there are more columns in my big table), filtered according to my conditions, and summarized the counts. The code below works like a charm and gives me what I want.

```
  group_by(col1) %>%
  filter(str_detect(col1, "^[[:alpha:]]{2,4}$")) %>%
  summarize(N = n())
```

I don't know though, how to include in a separate column also those counts, which appeared in other rows but were omitted. E.g. "ta" occurred twice in the row "ta ta pa". The target output is the one below:

```
col1       N    N_other

ta         3    2
pum        1    0
wam        1    2
```

Would appreciate a hint how to solve the problem. Hope my question is clear enough, if not please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means pretty, but it might be helpful. This assumes you want 2-4 letter words extracted from `col1`, and then for those extracted words, to count up how many there are by themselves, as well as multiple in a single row/string.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(str_ex1 = str_extract(col1, "^[[:alpha:]]{2,4}$"),
         str_ex2 = str_extract(col1, paste(str_ex1, collapse = "|")),
         count1 = str_count(col1, paste(str_ex1, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  filter(count1 > 0) %>%
  group_by(str_ex1, str_ex2) %>%
  summarise(count2 = sum(count1)) %>%
  mutate(N_type = if_else(is.na(str_ex1), "N_other", "N")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = str_ex2, names_from = N_type, values_from = count2) %>%
  replace_na(list(N_other = 0))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  str_ex2     N N_other
  <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
1 pum         1       0
2 ta          3       2
3 wam         1       2
```

**Edit (3/22/20)**

OP provided a subset of own data for testing (50 rows as suggested):

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 57L, 4L, 47L, 47L, 
39L, 9L, 18L, 34L, 34L, 18L, 56L, 14L, 23L, 42L, 53L, 9L, 9L, 
17L, 45L, 1L, 30L, 30L, 18L, 52L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 34L, 47L, 34L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 
34L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("", "[is]", "[is] + [is]", "[is] + [is]+ [is]", 
"[is] + pa", "[is] + pum tsa + [is]", "[is] pa", "[is] to go", 
"c", "dza pam pa", "dza tsa", "gwa", "gwa pa", "gwam pa (and) tsa", 
"gwam param pam gwam", "gwap pa", "katapum", "pa", "pa pa", "pa pa ta", 
"pa pampa pa", "pak", "pam pa ta", "para", "puk", "pum pam pa", 
"stn sta pa", "ta", "ta pa", "ta um pa", "tan tan pam pa", "tara", 
"tok", "tsa", "tsa [close] da", "tsa pa", "tsa pa tsa", "tsa para pa", 
"tsa ta", "tsak", "tsak pak", "tsan tsan tsa", "tsarara + [is]", 
"um", "um pa", "um pa pa", "wa", "wa pa", "wa pa [is] pa", "wa sta um pa", 
"wa wa", "wa wa pu pa pa pa", "wa wa ta pa", "wak wak", "wak wak pa pa", 
"wam pa", "wam pam pa", "wam pam pa pa", "wam pam pam pa", "wap pa", 
"wo", "wuk"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"touch + yes", "yes", "yes (for himself)"), class = "factor"), 
    col3 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "yes", 
    "yes (hand mov)", "yes (hands mov)", "yes (head mov)", "yes (index finger)"
    ), class = "factor"), col4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "yes"), class = "factor"), col5 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "yes", "yes (part of it)", 
    "yes\n"), class = "factor"), col6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "repeats the mov", "yes", "yes (see next line)"
    ), class = "factor"), col7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("K", "M"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code was revised as follows:

```
df %>%
  mutate(col1 = as.character(col1)) %>%
  select(col1) %>%
  mutate(str_ex1 = str_extract(col1, "^[[:alpha:]]{2,4}$"),
         str_ex2 = str_extract(col1, paste(str_ex1, collapse = "|")),
         count1 = str_count(col1, paste(str_ex1, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  filter(count1 > 0) %>%
  group_by(str_ex1, str_ex2) %>%
  summarise(count2 = sum(count1)) %>%
  mutate(N_type = if_else(is.na(str_ex1), "N_other", "N")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(str_ex1 = coalesce(str_ex1, str_ex2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = str_ex1, names_from = N_type, values_from = count2) %>%
  replace_na(list(N_other = 0))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  str_ex1     N N_other
  <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
1 pa          3       6
2 pak         1       0
3 para        2       0
4 puk         2       0
5 tsa         7       4
6 wa          3      16
```

Also note, `col1` is a factor, so this was made to a plain character vector. In addition, I included `select(col1)` to only look at `col1` and ignore other columns.

Comment: I ran the code on my actual data. I do get an input but the numbers are not correct (checked random samples). The only difference I see to your output is that "N_other" is in your table <dbl> and in my case it's a list. Also I don't see characters with more than 3 letters. They disappeared now

Comment: My table is big one and even though I added some new col in the dummy table, your code work. That is not what helps me. What I can say though is that my table consists of columns with factors and integers. I tried to convert them characters doing ```df $col1 <- as.character(df$col1) ``` and get this same wrong output. I am missing smth and I don't know what

Comment: Sure. I added the subset as requested. Thank you for trying.

Comment: @Jo-Achna I noticed the additional data in an edit to my answer - I included, as well as revised code and output. Let me know if this provides the result you were looking for.

Comment: There is one more thing that crossed my mind. If I would like to add a percentage of relative frequencies (N) in a new column, what could I do? I tried to add `mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * N/sum(n), N), "%"))` but the output is wrong. It must have smth to do with the fact that N is not numerical.

Comment: You have a small `n` in `sum(n)` - is that intentional? It probably should be large 'N'

Comment: It was a typo in the comment. Should be `mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * N/sum(N), N), "%"))` but it still doesn't work, with capital N as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: I tried it out, and got: 16.7%, 5.6%, 11.1%, 11.1%, 38.9%, and 16.7% - what did you get? And what should it be? Currently, it is computing percent column-wise. If you want row-wise percent (such as 33.3%, 100%, 100%, etc.) let me know.